How do I get my script to activate other parts of my script
When my script is set up without a return between like this it activates:
p::
Sleep 6000
Send, {o}

o::
loop, 1
{

Sleep 3000
etc etc

But If I want to send p or o anywhere else in the script it doesn't work. Is there a solution to this?
The things I've currently thought of are:
Remove all returns but the one down the very bottom
Have separate autohotkey scripts for every different thing I want to do rather than one master script that covers a whole topic
Just re-paste the scripting that would happen when I would want to have the script activate it but that wouldn't solve the issue I'm having and make it more messy as I'm trying to do this to keep everything condensed and not repetitive
